# En mi vista me devuelve el valor entre corchetes, como lo devuelvo sin esos corchetes, tan solo obteniendo el valor en este caso 5? - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

Esto me devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Controllador es este:

```
 public function index(){   

 $id = Personal::select('id')->where('id_user','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
 $asistencias = Asistencia::where('id_personal', $id)->get();
 return view('asistencia.index',compact('asistencias','id'));                        
 }
```

En Mi vista lo llamo asi:

```
{!! Form::label('id', 'ID') !!}
{!! Form::text('id',$id, ['class' => 'form-control block w-full mt-1' . ($errors->has('id') ? ' border-red-600' : '')]) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controllador:

```
public function index(){   

$id = Personal::select('id')->where('id_user','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
$asistencias = Asistencia::where('id_personal', $id[0]->id)->get();
return view('asistencia.index',compact('asistencias','id'));                        
}
```

Vista:

```
{!! Form::label('id', 'ID') !!}
{!! Form::text('id',$id[0]->id, ['class' => 'form-control block w-full mt-1' . 
($errors->has('id') ? ' border-red-600' : '')]) !!}
```